# Coefficient of $x^{r}$

Tags: linear-algebra, binomial-coefficients, combinations

I was willing to find the coefficient of $x^{49}$ in the expression $(x+1)(x+2)...(x+100)$

But is there any kind of generalisation of finding the coefficient of $x^r , 0<r<n$ in the expression
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x+i)$$

Did there exist closed form ?
If not

Then answer my former question only .
Thanks in advance. I feel i will get an answer here surely. I asked it on brilliant.org but no one replied there.

Comment: The coefficients are closely related to unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Unsigned_Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind

Answer (score 1):

In general you have $\prod^n_i (x - \lambda_i ) = x^n - e_1(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n) \cdot x^{n-1} + \dots + (-1)^{n} e_n(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$

where $e_k(X_1,\dots,X_n) = \sum_{1\le i_1 < \dots < i_k \le n} X_{i_1} \cdots X_{i_k}$.

Edit: knowing that $x^{\underline{n}} = x(x-1)\dots(x-(n+1)) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} s_{n,k} \cdot x^k$, (where $s_{n,k}$ are the stirling numbers of the first kind) you get a connection to the elementary symmetric polynomials:

coeff. of $x^{n-k}$ $ = (-1)^k e_k(0,\dots,n-1) = (-1)^k s_{n,n-k}$

Comment: can you solve the expression for 49 case ?

Comment: This has to do with Vieta's theorems, which also exist for polynomials of a degree higher than 2.

Comment: The $e_k$ are called elementary symmetric polynomials. Evaluating $e_{51}(1,\dots,100)$ does not seem so nice...

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of $x^{49}$ is quite large.  I get

$$
440203875867633250993831537954997438935190133369140390700 \\
030010603623221873719241373833402230030817400306028361250
$$

which has $114$ digits.  Offhand I don't see a quick way of obtaining the coefficients you want; technically, you can get closed forms, but they're not trivial to compute by hand.  Computer aid makes it trivial, of course, but I'm not sure that's what you're after...

Comment: So may I know which software you used for doing this calculation @brian

Comment: @AmanRajput: I don't remember what I used.  It may have been Maxima.

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed formula available which could represent the coefficient of $x^r$ in
\begin{align*}
  \prod_{k=1}^n(x+k)
  \end{align*}

But, as already indicated in a comment we can find a representation of the product using *[Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheFirstKind.html)* $(-1)^{n-k}\left[\begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array}\right]$.

> We start with close relatives of Stirling numbers, called *[unsigned Lah numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lah_number)* $L(n,k)$.
>   \begin{align*}
>   L(n,k)=\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n!}{k!}\qquad\qquad k,n>0
>   \end{align*}
>
> With these numbers we can write *rising factorials* $x^{\overline{n}}$ in terms of *falling factorials* $x^{\underline{n}}$ (and vice versa).
>   \begin{align*}
>   x^{\overline{n}}=x(x+1)\cdots (x+n-1)=\sum_{k=1}^nL(n,k)x^{\underline{k}}\qquad \qquad n>0
>   \end{align*}
>
> The falling factorials $x^{\underline{n}}$ can be expressed in terms of *[Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Unsigned_Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)* $(-1)^{n-k}\left[\begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array}\right]$.
>   \begin{align*}
>   x^{\underline{n}}=x(x-1)\cdots (x-n+1)=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{n-k}\left[\begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array}\right]x^k\qquad\qquad n>0
>   \end{align*}

Putting all together we obtain a generating function for rising factorials:

> \begin{align*}
>   x^{\overline{n}}&=x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^nL(n,k)\sum_{j=1}(-1)^{j-k}\left[\begin{array}{c} n \\ k \end{array}\right]x^j\\
>   &=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n!}{k!}
>   \sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^{k-j}\left[\begin{array}{c} k \\ j \end{array}\right]x^j\tag{1}\\
>  &=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n!}{k!}(-1)^{n-k}
>   \left[\begin{array}{c} k \\ j \end{array}\right]x^j\tag{2}
>   \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we write the *unsigned Lah numbers* in terms of binomial coefficients
- In (2) we exchange the sums

> It's convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator to denote the coefficient of $[x^n]$ in a series. This way we can write the coefficient of $x^r$ in OPs product using (2) as
>
> \begin{align*}
> [x^r](x+1)\cdots (x+n)&=[x^{r+1}]x(x+1)\cdots (x+n)\\
> &=[x^{r+1}]x^{\underline{n+1}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=r+1}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k-1}\frac{(n+1)!}{k!}(-1)^{n+1-k}
>   \left[\begin{array}{c} k \\ r+1 \end{array}\right]\qquad\qquad 0<r\leq n\\
> \end{align*}
>
> The coefficient of $x^{49}$ in OPs product can be calculated as
>   \begin{align*}
>   [x^{49}]&(x+1)\cdots (x+100)=\sum_{k=50}^{101}\binom{100}{k-1}\frac{101!}{k!}(-1)^{k-1}\left[\begin{array}{c} k \\50 \end{array}\right]
>   \end{align*}

With some  help of Wolfram Alpha we see the sum coincides with the result of @BrianTung.

*Note:* We could also represent the Stirling numbers of the first kind in terms of binomial coefficients. See this *[related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34151/simple-efficient-representation-of-stirling-numbers-of-the-first-kind)* in MO.